# How to calculate various model speed in FPS for my GPU? In Darknet

Tags: object-detection, frame-rate, yolo, darknet

I am using [Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) in my object-detection project. And I want to create a similar chart like this:

[image]

For my GPU and various models. How can I calculate the speed of the model in FPS? 
I have tried to do this that way, but I don't know that it has sense and is correct:

I run mAP calculation for my validation-set and get this information in the output: 
[image]

So if I have in my validation-set 300 of images, that model speed = 300/28 = 10,71 FPS

Is it correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve Zaretii

Thanks for your answer, I ask AlexeyAB from Darknet the same question and he told me as you that my solution is limited by HDD / SDD disk.

So he enable now solution for this type of model speed measurment:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/4627

> I added -benchmark flag for detector demo, now you can use command 2652263
>
> `./darknet detector demo obj.data yolo.cfg yolo.weights test.mp4 -benchmark`
>
> But for very fast models the bottleneck will be in the Video Capturing from file/camera, >or in Video Showing (you can disable showing by using -dont_show flag).

I think that it is the best solution, you only need the newest version of Darknet (from AlexeyAB).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the total detection time includes the time of loading images from the disk. If you have HDD, this time is higher than detection time for some fast models.

One way to get average speed would be:
- Convert image to darknet format
- Start timer
- process image
- Stop timer
- Average this time

Please note that these functions: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c#L661-L665 take some CPU time. It should be ignored if you want time spend on GPU.